# Simple Powershell Script to Pass a String to a TCP connection?

Tags: powershell, tcp, powershell-2.0

I have the following entry in a Linux shell script:

```
loginString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
portNum="12345"
conRes=$(echo -e -n "${loginString}" | socat STDIO tcp4:127.0.0.1:${portNum})
```

Simply put, it opens a tcp connection to **"127.0.0.1:12345"** and passes across the loginString.

I then record the response to confirm whether or not my application is accepting connections (any response is fine, as long as it is a response).

But, how would I convert this to run in Powershell (and just to be awkward, Powershell v2.0).

I've come across various posts with long scripts that seem to do all manner of things, and take a whole range of inputs, but I just need something simple (if that is possible).

Is there a way of doing this in Powershell v2?

Comment: Not sure if just testing the port will suffice your need but you can do post testing using TCP Sockets: `$tcp = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient;
$tcp.connect('hydlpt487', 3389);
$tcp.Connected;`

Comment: This link from [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/536deee8-9fa7-4553-9454-d1faf468b64b/send-data-on-remote-port?forum=winserverpowershell) also has similar thing in simple format.

Comment: OK cheers, that link looks promising. I can see the connection attempt at the other end, but the string being passed is wrong. I have added ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353658 to explain it in more detail.