# How to pass a Hex String to a TCP connection and Read the Result

Tags: powershell, tcp, hex, powershell-2.0

I have the following script (thanks to @SavindraSingh for the link).

I am trying to pass the `$message` below to the `$remotehost $port` and capture the response.

```
$port=12345
$remoteHost = "1.2.3.4"
$message="\x40\x00\x23\x01\x00\x00\x00\x40"

$socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($remoteHost, $port)

$data = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message)

$stream = $socket.GetStream()
$stream.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
```

The problem is that the `ASCII.GetBytes` converts each character to it's individual 'bytes' (as expected).
However, if I simply do `$data=$message` I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "\x40\x00\x23\x01\x00\x00\x00\x40", for "Write" to type "System.Byte[]"
: "Cannot convert value "\x40\x00\x23\x01\x00\x00\x00\x40" to type "System.Byte[]". Error: "Cannot convert value
"\x40\x00\x23\x01\x00\x00\x00\" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."""
At line:13 char:14
+ $stream.Write <<<< ($data, 0, $data.Length)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

How can I pass across my `$message` (a string of hex values).

And how would I see the response (`write-host $stream` just says `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`).

**--- UPDATE 2016-07-14 ---**

Based on the documentation, and pieces I've gleaned elsewhere, I've added the following to try and Read the response:

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)

$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
$encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

$rawresponse = ""

$response1 = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
$response2 = $encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $rawresponse)

write-host $response1
write-host $response2
```

But from this `$response1` always returns 0, 20 , or 21 And `$response2` returns nothing.
I was expecting a text string similar to `#@3e1###f9` which is what my application should be returning.

Have I misunderstood something somewhere?

Comment: `$message = 0x40,0x00,0x23,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40`

Comment: Ah Ha, removing the " " from the $message was the one thing I didn't think of trying. I can now see the connection correctly arrives at the other end. All I need to do now is find out how I can capture the response?

Comment: $stream.Read*something*() ?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ok cheers, I'm getting closer. I've added some additional info above, as It's not quite what I was expecting.